# Sed function (Bash) - Changing way of commented lines

Tags: bash, sed

I have such task to do but I have no idea how to write it with sed function.
I have to change the way on commenting in a file from:

```
//something6
//something4
//something5
//something3
//something2
```

to

```
/*something6
* something4
* something5
* something3
* something2*/
```

from

```
//something6
//something4
//something5
//something3
//something2
```

to

```
/*something6
something4
something5
something3
something2*/
```

from

```
/*something6
* something4
* something5
* something3
* something2*/
```

to

```
//something6
//something4
//something5
//something3
//something2
```

from

```
/*something6
something4
something5
something3
something2*/
```

to

```
//something6
//something4
//something5
//something3
//something2
```

Those 4 patterns must be made by sed function (I guess but not sure about that).
Tried doing it but without luck. I can replace single words to other ones but how to change the way of commenting? No clue. Would be very gratefull for help and assisstance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows no search effort.

Comment: This sort of thing is generally a bit difficult, because you're going from a line-oriented comment to a delimited one. You need to extract the comment first, and then re-insert it. For example how would you handle: `something_not_comment // some comment`

Comment: @Darth I mean have you try to do it yourself?

Comment: This is trivial in awk, does it have to be sed ?

Comment: #Thomas as I said I tried it but it does not go well. I can do easy things with sed but more complicated ones are not so clear for me.
@JID it has to work to be honest I do not care what function it is ;).

Comment: Show us what you tried.  Also, what is the difference between the two pairs of blocks of 'to be replaced' and 'replace with'?  The first two are converting C++-style comments to a complex C-style comment; the second two are doing to converse.  Is the text of the comments really fixed?  Are there always 5 lines in the block?  Do the C-style comments really have to be as shown with the trailing `*/` on the same line as the last comment text?

Comment: This is my interpretation of the instruction I have received.
It says: Please write a script that allows to change style of comments in source files for example : /* ....  */ -> // ... . The style of comment is an argument of the script.

I have tried to use just typical sed -i 's/'"$lookingfor"'/'"$changing"'/g' $filename.
But it throw errors when i try to give as parameters // and /* because they are kind of regular expressions...

Comment: Heres one of the written awfully in in awk.Rework it to do the others `awk 't{(!/\/\//&&t=t"*/")&&x="";print t}sub("//",""){!x++&&$0="/*"$0;t=$0}!x&&!(t=0);END{if(t)print t"*/"}'`

Answer (score 0):

Given that the task is:

> Please write a script that allows to change style of comments in source files for example : `/* .... */` goes to `// ...`. The style of comment is an argument of the script.
>
> I have tried to use just typical:
>
> ```
>  sed -i 's/'"$lookingfor"'/'"$changing"'/g' $filename
> ```

In this context, either `$lookingfor` or `$changing` or both will contain slashes, so that simple formulation doesn't work, as you correctly observe.

The conversion of `//` comments to `/*` comments is easy as long as you know that you can choose an arbitrary character to separate the sections of the `s///` command, such as `%`.  So, for example, you could use:

```
sed -i.bak -e 's%// *\(.*\)%/*\1 */%'
```

This looks for a double-slash followed by zero or more spaces and anything and converts it to `/* anything */`.

The conversion of `/*` comments is much harder.  There are two cases to be concerned about:

```
/* A single line comment */

/*
** A multiline comment
*/
```

That's before you get into:

```
/* OK */ "/* OK */" /* Really?! */
```

which is a single line containing two comments and a string containing text that outside a string would look like a comment.  This I am studiously ignoring!  Or, more accurately, I am studiously deciding that it will be OK when converted to:

```
// OK */ "/* OK */" /* Really?!
```

which isn't the same at all, but serves you right for writing convoluted C in the first place.

You can deal with the first case with something like:

```
sed -e '\%/\*\(.*\)\*/% { s%%//\1%; n; }'
```

I have the grouping braces and the `n` command in there so that single line comments don't also match the second case:

```
    -e '\%/\*%,\%\*/% {
            \%/\*% { s%/\*\(.*\)%//\1%; n; }
            \%\*/% { s%\(.*\)\*/%//\1%; n; }
            s%^\( *\)%\1//%
        }'
```

The first line selects a range of lines between one matching `/*` and the next matching `*/`.  The `\%` tells `sed` to use the `%` instead of `/` as the search delimiter.  There are three operations within the outer grouping `{` … `}`:

1. Convert `/*anything` into `//anything` and start on the next line.
2. Convert `anything*/` into `//anything` and start on the next line.
3. Convert any other line so that it preserves leading blanks but puts `//` after them.

This is still ridiculously easy to subvert if the comments are maliciously formed.  For example:

```
/* a comment */ int x = 0;
```

is mapped to:

// a comment int x = 0;

Fixing problems like that, and the example with a string, is something I'd not even start trying in `sed`.  And that's before you get onto the legal but implausible C comments, like:

```
/\
\
* comment
*\
\
/
/\
/\
noisiness \
commentary \
continued
```

Which contains just two comments (but does contain two comments!).  And before you decide to deal with trigraphs (`??/` is a backslash).  Etc.

So, a moderate approximation to a C to C++ comment conversion is:

```
sed -e '\%/\*\(.*\)\*/% { s%%//\1%; n; }' \
    -e '\%/\*%,\%\*/% {
            \%/\*% { s%/\*\(.*\)%//\1%; n; }
            \%\*/% { s%\(.*\)\*/%//\1%; n; }
            s%^\( *\)%\1//%
        }' \
    -i.bak "$@"
```

I'm assuming you aren't using a C shell; if you are, you need more backslashes at the ends of the lines in the script so that the multi-line single-quoted `sed` command is treated correctly.